Getting OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound error microsoft graph api for sendEmail
Trying to send email using microsoft graph api but getting below error
{"error":{"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid '0d41112c-dde8-4984-b7f0-bb346e0560b8' does not exist.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"f9cb3ea5-e9db-42fa-a399-bf16784bf768","oAuthEventcV":"4+rYj/snVGgHNU39QbnSrg.1.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant","requestId":"748d7aed-9769-4f9a-9fcd-6f3942369fb4","date":"2024-10-24T17:49:25"}}}
$provider = new GenericProvider([
        'clientId' => $config['microsoft']['clientId'],
        'clientSecret' => $config['microsoft']['clientSecret'],
        'redirectUri' => $redirectUrl,
        'urlAuthorize' => $config['microsoft']['loginBaseUrl'] . "/" . $config['microsoft']['tenantId'] . "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        'urlAccessToken' => $config['microsoft']['loginBaseUrl'] . "/" . $config['microsoft']['tenantId'] . "/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    ]);


    $scope = 'openid email profile https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access'

   $provider->getAuthorizationUrl([
     'scope' => $scope,
     'state' => base64_encode(json_encode($state))
   ]);


Could you include more details like how you generated access token and what type of user account you are using? personal Microsoft account or local account?

updated...We are using personal account @Sridevi

What API permissions you granted in your app registration and what account type you selected while creating application?

openid email profile Mail.Send Mail.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All User.Read.All offline_access is scope with account type Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)

Note that, for personal accounts you need to create app registration with account type as  "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

Yes we have selected account type as Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)

You need to select third option as account type while creating app registration https://i.imgur.com/HYlyL6m.png

We have only two options showing in my app registration screen
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lkrq2QtrKtn71ECVFPQVh1EhLEFdqnNQ/view?usp=sharing

You cannot change to that account type for existing applications via Portal. Could you try creating new app registration with account type as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"?

As you are sending mail from personal Microsoft account, make sure create app registration with "Account type" as below:

Now, I granted Mail.Send API permission of Delegated type in above application like this:

Now, I ran below authorization URL in browser and picked personal Microsoft account to login like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=appId
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=Mail.Send
&state=12345


Consent Prompt:

After approving the consent, I got code value in address bar as below::

In my case, I used Postman to generate access token using authorization code flow with below parameters:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: Mail.Send
code: <code_from_above>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms

Response:

You can now use this access token to send mail from personal Microsoft account user successfully.
